# How to get Count value in a HasMany relationship when querying sub Models?

Tags: loopbackjs

On a Category model I created, I have the following relation:

```
"subscriptions": 
{ 
"type": "hasMany", 
"model": "Subscription" 
"foreignKey": "",
   "options": { "nestRemoting": true } } }
```

How could I get the Count() result when running:

```
this.userService.getCategories(this.currentUser.id, 
  {include: {relation: 'subscriptions', scope: {type: 'count'}}})
  .subscribe((data: any[]) => { this.categories = data };
```

I would like to count the number of subscription when getting the categories belonging to the user, in the same observable().

Like show above, I tried with the scope of type 'count'. nothing comes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer:
Loopback provides the 'include' filter to be able to retrieve related models.
As a consequence an Observable is retrieved. It does contain the relationship.
Getting the Count() is as simple as writing `{{category.subscriptions.length}}`in the HTML.

Hope this helps.